# Select the week number of the date picked using jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code for selecting a date which I then want to convert to a week number.

```
    $(".calendar").datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            dateFormat: "'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)),
            alert($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)))
        }
    });
```

The alert shows the correct week number, but the date does not reformat at all.

I can't move the dateFormat function outside of the onSelect because this causes nothing to happen.

What I would like to achieve is the text field to say something like "Week Number 13"

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/ENG66/

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the goal here. What are you trying to achieve? Display the week number instead of the date in the input-field?

Comment: That's exactly it @pecka85... sorry if I've not made it all that clear. My mind is a mess with trying to work it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/ENG66/11/

In the onselect event, you need to use .val() to override the setting of the textbox value

```
$(".calendar").datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).val("'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
        }
    });​
```

**EDIT**

As Igor Shastin pointed out in his comment below we already have the text box in `inst.input`

```
inst.input.val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
```

Comment: I think this is slighly better solution, as soon as we already have the <input> element: http://jsfiddle.net/ENG66/12/

Comment: Feel free to update your post with my code, I would not mind, especially since your post is marked as the answer.

Comment: $.datepicker.iso8601Week() will return false week number if the `dateText` is not in ISO 8601 format. 
So I'm suggesting using `$(this).datepicker("getDate")` to replace `dateText`, 
so the line will be like  
`$(this).val("'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week($(this).datepicker("getDate")));`

Answer (score 2):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ENG66/7/)**.

```
$(".calendar").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        dateFormat: "'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)),
        $(this).val('Week:' + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers assume that the date format can be handled natively by Javascript. In the case of short European dates (dd/mm/yyyy, as opposed to the American mm/dd/yyyy), you can get the date value via datepicker itself, which will handle the conversion automatically.

```
$("#week_field").val( $.datepicker.iso8601Week( $("#date_field").datepicker( "getDate" ) ));
```

You can set a different date format for datepicker like this

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( {dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"} );
```