# jQuery UI Datepicker - disable every second week

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker and I need a functionality that disables every second week.

For example: All days of even weeks (2,4,6..) is enabled and can be picked - But all days of odd weeks (1,3,5..) are disabled and can not be picked.

I know I can disable specific days/or dates with beforeshowday. But this is not what I'm after..

Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `datepicker`'s **`beforeShowDay`** function to disable. Below code uses moment to make getting week easier but you can try something else as well:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay:function(d){
          var m=moment(d);
          //week number is even
          var en=m.week()%2===0;
          //its first and monday
          en|=(m.date()===1 && m.isoWeekday()===1);
          return [en,"","Odd Week"];
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Updated to enable 1st Monday in odd weeks. Check with `1-June-2015`

Comment: Got a problem with your code: When setting first firstDay: 1 (Monday) in jquery-ui.js, all disabled sundays gets enabled. Perhaps any easy fix to this?

Comment: Below "/* Date picker manager." in jquery-ui.js, there is an setting "firstDay: 1, // The first day of the week, Sun = 0, Mon = 1, ..."

When setting this to 1, all disabled sundays were switched (odd/even weeks).

Anyhow, I ended up with specifying the dates manually. It does make more sense to me than disabling the whole week (available weekend days etc.). Thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: or use for the week: `var nWeekOfYear = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(d));` as seen in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515882/1856258](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515882/1856258)